# Django and Openshift - ImportError: No module named settings

Tags: django, openshift

I am trying to write a simple Zinnia blog on Django. I am trying to deploy it Openshift and at wits end trying to identify this error. I am so lost on this for the last week! What could be throwing this error ? I am checking my Python path and seems okay. Git pushes successfully(Django 1.8, Python 2.7)

```
remote: Starting Python 2.7 cartridge (Apache+mod_wsgi)
remote: Application directory "wsgi/" selected as DocumentRoot
remote: $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION ENV VAR detected
remote: Application "wsgi/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py" selected as default WSGI entry point
remote: --> ACTION HOOK: post_deploy being done <--
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

The WSGI.py file is like this

```
import os import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi',   'myproject')) 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")  
application = get_wsgi_application()

virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR'] + 'python/virtenv/'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib/python2.7/site-packages')

virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py') 
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass
```

The manage.py file is like this

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # GETTING-STARTED: change 'myproject' to your project name:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

The error message is the following -

```
==> app-root/logs/python.log <==
[Sat Jul 30 13:41:44 2016] [error] [client 127.7.219.129]   File      "/var/lib/openshift/5789ce167628e144ee000113/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
[Sat Jul 30 13:41:44 2016] [error] [client 127.7.219.129]       self._setup(name)
[Sat Jul 30 13:41:44 2016] [error] [client 127.7.219.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/5789ce167628e144ee000113/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
[Sat Jul 30 13:41:44 2016] [error] [client 127.7.219.129]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Sat Jul 30 13:41:44 2016] [error] [client 127.7.219.129]   File  "/var/lib/openshift/5789ce167628e144ee000113/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
[Sat Jul 30 13:41:44 2016] [error] [client 127.7.219.129]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Sat Jul 30 13:41:44 2016] [error] [client 127.7.219.129]   File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Sat Jul 30 13:41:44 2016] [error] [client 127.7.219.129]     __import__(name)
[Sat Jul 30 13:41:44 2016] [error] [client 127.7.219.129] ImportError: No  module named settings
```

Any help would be much appreciated....This is very depressing!

Comment: According to https://developers.openshift.com/languages/python/getting-started.html you seem to be expecting the Python virtual environment in a different location than OpenShift puts it for you. Thus you activation is likely failing, with it being silently ignored, thus why can't find installed Django module.

Comment: Have you made sure that the module is in your requirements.txt (or wherever you are setting up your dependencies for your application)?